# flip box height of back side, also doesnot work on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to flip div/box, it works well. but the problem is height of back side. 
because it is higher than height of front side. so flip div always push down to next element (eg: Container2). and there is always space between flip div and next elements.

In addition, when I run this code on IE, its flips the div but don't show the right content. just try my demo in IE and Chrome. you will find the issue.

also I have attached the image. I hope they will help to understand the issue.

**First State want to manage this height/space from both content and container2**
[image: Front side of Flip div/box. so when I click on Edit, it flips and shows backside]

**2nd State after clicked on edit link**
[image: this is backside of flip card. when I click on save icon it just flip back. (not saving data at the moment)]

I hope I have explained enough.

Thank you...

**[demo code](http://jsfiddle.net/yznysfkh/)**

**HTML**

```
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="container">
<div class="flip">
    <div class="moveOnchange card">
        <div class="face front bgGrey">
            <div class=" portlet portletTodelete  ">
                <div class="portlet-header"> <span class="  "> Front   Side         </span>

                    <div class="dropdown pull-right "> 

                        <span class="pull-right ">
                        <span class="flipControl" >Edit <span    class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil pull-right flipLink"> </span> </span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <!-- portlet-content -->
                </div>
                <!-- portlet-header -->
            </div>
            <div class="portlet-content">content</div>
            <!-- portlet- -->
        </div>
        <!-- moveOnchange-->
         <div class="face back">
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="portlet">
                    <div class="flipForm bgGrey">          Back Side
                        <ul class="list-inline pull-right ">
                            <li class="flipControl"> <span class="pull-    right glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk gi-1x opacity7 "></span>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <hr class="hrflipForm">
                    </div>
                    <!-- Header Closed -->
                    <div class="portlet-content">
                        <br>text
                        <br>text
                        <br>text
                        <br>text
                        <br>text
                        <br>text
                        <br>text
                        <br>text
                        <br>text
                        <br>text
                        <br>text
                        <br>text</div>
                    <!--- Portlet content -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container2 container border">container 2</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.flipForm {
    padding:5px;
}

.bgGrey {
    background: #efefef;
}

.portlet {
    border:solid 1px red;
    padding: 10px;
}

.portlet-header {
    padding: 0.2em 0.3em;
    /*margin-bottom: 0.5em;*/
    position: relative;
}

.portlet-content {
    border:blue 1px solid;
    padding: 0.4em;
}

.portlet-placeholder {
    border: 1px dotted black;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    height: 50px;
}



/************* Flip and show Form. ************/

.flip {
    -webkit-perspective: 800;
    perspective: 800;
    position: relative;

}

.flip .card.flipped {
    -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg);

    transform: rotatey(-180deg);

}

.flip .card {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.flip .card .face {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 100%;

}

.flip .card .front {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    height: auto;
}

.flip .card .back {
    height: auto;
    -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
    transform: rotatey(-180deg);
}

.inner {
    height: auto !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
}

.container2 {
    border:solid 1px green;
    height:50px;
    padding:5px;
}
```

Comment: [IE has bad support for transforms3d](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d).

Comment: k I got it. about IE

Comment: @RajanKumar But this problem with different height appear also in Chrome.

Comment: @RajanKumar But I see you have other problems in IE, with the text...

Comment: @Simba No, what I understand is he has a problem with the height of the flipped  box.

Comment: In IE it is just more visible the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Set min-height and margin-bottom.
http://jsfiddle.net/9w26kzc6/6/

```
.portlet-content {
    border:blue 1px solid;
    padding: 0.4em;
    min-height: 400px;
}
.flip {
    -webkit-perspective: 800;
    perspective: 800;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 450px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

And add this:

```
.flip .card .face {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 100%;
-ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

And add background-color:

```
.flip .card .back {
    height: auto;
    -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
    transform: rotatey(-180deg);
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: that's problem I cant set min-height. because I don't have enough content for front side. and most of the time back div has lot data to show.

Comment: I think you can set anyway a min-height if you want to use this effect.

Comment: I have tried but I doesn't work. as I want.

Comment: I personally have dropped this effect because of the difference of front and back content. I added this link http://jsfiddle.net/9w26kzc6/6/. I hope it helps. I don't have other idea now.

Comment: I want something like this. http://jsfiddle.net/7osejwmh/

when you hover first 3 divs they flip and increase the size of back div. but don't push the content to bottom or slide

Comment: Well, then set height: 150px; and not min-height.

Comment: This is what I think, the solution of this problem is to set height or min-height.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure this will work, but I think it would:

Css:

```
        .flipForm {
        padding:5px;
    }

    .bgGrey {
        background: #efefef;
    }

    .portlet {
        border:solid 1px red;
        padding: 5px;
    }

.portlet-header {
        padding: 0.2em 0.3em;
        /*margin-bottom: 0.5em;*/
        position: relative;
    }

    .portlet-content {
        border:blue 1px solid;
        padding: 0.4em;
    }

    .portlet-placeholder {
        border: 1px dotted black;
        margin: 0 0 10px 0;
        height: 50px;
    }



    /************* Flip and show Form. ************/

    .flip {
        -webkit-perspective: 800;
        perspective: 800;
        position: relative;

    }

    .flip .card.flipped {
        -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg);

        transform: rotatey(-180deg);

    }

    .flip .card {
        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transition: 0.5s;
    }

    .flip .card .face {
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        z-index: 2;
        height: 100%;

    }

    .flip .card .front {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
        height: auto;
    }

    .flip .card .back {
        height: auto;
        -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
        transform: rotatey(-180deg);
    }

    .inner {
        height: auto !important;
        margin: 0px !important;
    }

    .container2 {
        border:solid 1px green;
        height:35px;
        padding:5px;
    }
```

[PLease see my demo page](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/yznysfkh/8/)

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/yznysfkh/8/)

Comment: but I can still see the white space.

Comment: ya wait sir @RajanKumar

Comment: you want reduce white space@RajanKumar

Comment: yaa. above the container 2. because that is height from back side.

Comment: just a minutes sir@RajanKumar

Comment: Please See my latest update demo file sir@RajanKumar

Comment: thank you for your efforts but I don't want to increase the size of height. because don't have enough content to show. on front card

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89057/discussion-between-rajan-kumar-and-ivin-raj).